# Linq-To-Sql: Why my changeset is always zero?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a query similar to the one on [msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
// Query the database for the row to be updated. 
var query =
    from ord in db.Orders
    where ord.OrderID == 11000
    select ord;

// Execute the query, and change the column values 
// you want to change. 
foreach (Order ord in query)
{
    ord.ShipName = "Mariner";
    ord.ShipVia = 2;
    // Insert any additional changes to column values.
}

// Submit the changes to the database. 
try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    // Provide for exceptions.
}
```

What I want now, is a way to know the affected rows of last update command. I've tried using:

```
int affectedRows = dc.GetChangeSet().Updates.Count;
```

in various manner, but this instruction always getting me 0, even if the table is correctly updated.

Comment: Where are you calling it? Before or after `SubmitChanges`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dc.GetChangeSet()` tells you how many changes your LINQ to SQL context is planning to make when you call `SubmitChanges()`. It does not track the number of affected rows as reported by the database.

If you call `int affectedRows = dc.GetChangeSet().Updates.Count;` before calling `SubmitChanges`, you will see how many rows it expects to have affected. After calling `SubmitChanges`, there are no more pending changes, so you'll always get a zero count.